# <int:pk> or {pk} does not work in DRF router

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an Comment which have an Article foreign key (so Article have an "array" of comments). I need to build an url to fetch theese comments using article's pk, but when I am trying to do smth like "articles/int:article_pk/comments/" or "articles/{article_pk}/comments/" drf router crates static route with path "articles/{article_pk}/comments/". How can I implement getting a comments using article pk?

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('articles', articleAPI.ArticleAPI, basename='articles')
router.register('articles/comments', CommentAPI,  basename='comments')
```

Comment: Please show how you are using the routers...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem see upd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this same url to get comments as well.

`router.register('articles', articleAPI.ArticleAPI, basename='articles')`

add a new method to `Article` ModelViewSet

```
@action(methods=['get'], detail=True,
        url_path='comments', url_name='article-comments')
    article = self.get_object()
    serializer = CommentSerializer(queryset=article.comment_set.all(), many=True) # comment_set resembles the related name for article foreign key
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

In postman hit the url `articles/<article_id>/comments/` with GET method to get the comment list

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because that is not how routers are intended to be used. You don't specify the key when registering, you use the viewset to define it. Read the docs at [1].
[1]: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter

Comment: I have also ask how can I implement what have i described

Comment: Yes the combination with another path in urlpatterns as     path('articles/<int:article_pk>/', include(comment_router.urls)),, also stated by willem in other answer is correct approach for this. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

A router can indeed not do that. You will need to capture the `article_pk` in the `path` and then work with two routers, so:

```
article_router = DefaultRouter()
article_router.register('articles', articleAPI.ArticleAPI, basename='articles')

comment_router = DefaultRouter()
comment_router.register('comments', CommentAPI, basename='comments')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(article_router.urls)),
    path('articles/<int:article_pk>/', include(comment_router.urls)),
]
```